# In which model does this belong?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I often get confused as to which model to create functions. Let me try to explain my current situation with a simple made up example:

I have a `Log` model that contains all activities on our app. I want to get the activity for a specific user. Should I create a `getActivity($userId)` function in the `User` model or the `Log` model?

Comment: You should write in - Log model

Comment: If I were you I would have put getActivity function in Log model

Comment: You only ever have *one* model. Plural "models" is not a thing. You may and should have several *classes* of various sorts inside your model, but you never really have several models.

Comment: @deceze could you explain what you mean by I should only have one model?

Comment: "The model" in MVC is *your core app*. The model does everything your app does, it contains all the business logic and moving parts. That's what "the model" is in MVC. Views are a way to visualise the contents of your model, and controllers are the necessary glue that's needed to make the whole thing work in a concrete setting. That's what MVC is about, about separating these three conceptually distinct parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why not both?**

Of course, the main thing is to avoid code duplication as this would be difficult to maintain - and an ugly solution.

*The Log Model* could contain a method called `getActivity()` which fetches all activity (or based on any arguments needed for pagination and/or log levels). Additionally, for self-documenting purposes, create a method called `getUserActivity($userId)` - a method that hopefully looks selfexplainatory.

*The User Model* could now contain a method called `getActivity()` (again, with any arguments needed for pagination and/or log levels) which in turn calls the `getUserActivity()` method in your *Log* model.

**Is this the smartest choice?**

Well, there is never a single solution for any problem - but what I like about this solution is that you now have the possibilty to seperate the logic for each of the models, but still have a visible and functional link between them. Secondly, you know have the possibilty to chain User objects to log activity in an easy way.

Comment: For the record, the `getActivity` and `getUserActivity` could be the same method, with the right arguments, but I'm a fan of seperating the logic and naming for each use case.

Answer (score 0):

Since the main used database in your function will be the `"Log"` one, you should place it in the `Log` Model.